# Simulator slow-motion animations are now on?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios-simulator

A while ago I was experimenting, trying to see if i could get navigation items to animate and scroll between each other.

I don't know if this is related but suddenly without touching the simulator options I'm getting this message `Simulator slow-motion animations are now on` and moving between views is very slow, like 3 seconds. This occurs with all animation effects.

Any idea what I need to do to stop this ?

Comment: The shortcut changed to ⌘T in Xcode 6.

Comment: As of Xcode 8.2.1 and simulator version 10.0, Slow Animations increases animation duration by a factor of 10. A 1 second animation will take 10 seconds with Slow Animations enabled.

Comment: I wonder why they have even made this random feature.

Comment: Probably to debug animations and watch them slowly to ensure they do exactly what they should

Comment: Go to emulator from above menu debug>slow animations (command + T)

Answer (score 599, accepted):

The shortcut as of Xcode 6 is <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. This toggles it between on and off, so to turn it off just punch that combination.

Comment: So you don' think that its something that will have affect on release code ?

Comment: Could it be that if he's using a beta, he could have pressed shift 3 times and accidentally activated it?

Comment: @CodaFi: I didn't know about that! I'll have to try it.

Comment: I must admit, I hadn't heard about it either, but when I researched his problem, another thread on SO mentioned that beta simulator builds toggled that animation with a triple shift click.  Later posts say it was disabled...

Comment: This is triggered by triple-tapping Shift, but I occasionally see it triggered when I definitely haven't tapped Shift three times in a row without hitting other keys.

Comment: I triggered this by accident when validating field entry with strings like "'"''"'"'""'"  which is a combo of shift+quote and just quote but obviously it was the shift key being repeated 3 times in rapid sucsession regardless of what other key is pressed.

Comment: Hold down Command ⌘ and Shift ⇧, press Key H twice, you will see the slow-motion is turn off

Comment: This worked for me.    

I don't do iOS development, so I'm just curious: is this *feature* actually useful?

Comment: Definitely can be useful for troubleshooting to see your animations in slow-mo, but not very often. I keep getting this activated by mistake when I using the keyboard to simulate a press of the home button. It's very annoying! Is there a way to prevent it from going into slow-mo mode?

Comment: even more annoying, is that it can be turned on for the springboard and turned off for your app ...

Comment: @Undo: Noooooo anything but the arrow icon :(

Comment: @BoltClock New Apple keyboards don't have the arrow icon - it might have been confusing :)

Comment: @Undo: Oh, that's fair. Even my white MacBook from 2010 lacks the icon.

Comment: nd i was reseting my simulator again and again :D

Comment: use save my life bro. I tried restart the simulator, restart the xcode and even update the xcode :D

Comment: Sure was nice of them to use the same hotkey for opening a new Xcode or browser tab, allowing me to turn this on by accident and assume that Apple just shipped a simulator bug that they didn't feel like fixing.

Comment: As of XCode 11 this is no longer the shortcut, I cant seam to find if there is one at all.

Answer (score 44):

Just figured this out:

You can toggle slow-motion animations on and off by pressing Shift three times in succession while the iOS Simulator is in focus.

Comment: No wonder, I had no idea how this was getting turned on sometimes.

Comment: It also triggers if you hold Shift and press Cmd twice.

Comment: Wow, this is probably the dumbest, most unintuitive, 'why is this happening?' keystroke I've ever come acrossed.  Apparently I hit the shift key a lot because I seem to accidentally toggle this (incredibly useful when I actually want it) feature constantly.

Answer (score 28):

In the simulator at the top bar, go to `Debug` 
[image]

`Slow Animations` and check it off or on.

[image]

Nothing to it.

Comment: `⌘`+`T` doesn't seem to be a shortcut for me. But the debug option did the trick!

Answer (score 22):

because there's no home button in the iPad simulator since iOS 5.0, we need a key combination (shift+command+h), which may activate slow motion. This glitch keeps happening to me, and quite annoying.

Comment: I hate this too! I wish there was a way to turn off slow animations forever.

Comment: Oh, yeah. Command-Shift-h. That's what's doing it. I knew I wasn't hitting the shift key three times. Thanks!

Comment: It's actually just Command-Shift. If you hit them simultaneously, then it toggles slow animations. Very annoying.

Comment: it is happening to me all the time, when I press CMD-Shift-H to press the Home button. Especially annoying since the home button does not show up on my simulator due to my super shallow iMac screen

Answer (score 8):

I ran into this same problem, and it seems that now the shortcut is <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to toggle it on any app that you're running. If you're on the home screen it should toggle all of the base OS animation speeds.

Answer (score 7):

### In Xcode 11, the shortcut `command + T` didn't work for me.

---

### To solve it:

1. Open simulator
2. Click on the debug menu
3. deselect "Slow Animations" from the menu.
4. Done

[image]

Comment: The shortcut in Xcode 11 has been removed, but the feature is still usable through the debug menu at the top

Answer (score 4):

One reason this keeps happening to me is I use a VNC viewer to remotely work on my Mac mini, and it defaults to sending repeated keypresses whenever any key (including shift) is held down.

So even though "I" am not pressing shift multiple times, if I use the physical keyboard to enter text, then just holding shift down long enough to type a few letters results in the Mac seeing it multiple times and toggling the slow animations.

One work around is to not use the physical keyboard, but instead always "type" using the mouse to select letters on the simulators pop-up keyboard.

Answer (score 4):

When simulator is open, simulator window show 6 commands including file, edit, hardware, debug, window and help.

Just click on Debug and the first position is stop animation <kbd>window</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> command is use for it.

If the slow animation is checked then simply unchecked it.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't fix it with triple shift, or triple home.

Could not fix via Debug->Toggle Slow Animation either.

Instead, you can reset the whole damn thing: **iOS Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings.**

Note that I had 2 problems.. slow motion inside the app (which was toggled by the debug->toggle menu) and slow motion when I switch between apps, aka "everything". I was only able to fix the global slow mo by resetting.

Answer (score 1):

On 5.1 it can be toggled by hitting Shift twice, just like we do double-click on mouse.

Comment: actually, it's three times. See below.

Comment: @Flaviu, it worked for by hitting Shift twice. I verified it again.

Comment: Silly iOS dev tools. Mine definitely only works if you hit it three times. oh well.

Answer (score 0):

The shortcut as of Xcode 10.3 is `Command ⌘`+`T`. This toggles it between on and off, so to turn it off just punch that combination. And run your project again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the shortest way to close the slow animation in Simulator!

Step 1: Open the Simulator.

Step 2: On the left top of the window you'll find Debug[image: See here] in some of the options.

Step 3: Under Devices, you'll see an option ( Slow Animations ) is checked, Just Uncheck it !!

Done . :]