# Why there is no "Home" button in iPad simulator in iOS 5.1 SDK?

Tags: ipad, ios-simulator

How to simulator the action of "press the home button"?

Comment: The problem is when demoing the software it can be hard for some people to visualize.  I use the simulator when demoing to many people (big screen me in control V a phone between many with them pressing stuff).

Answer (score 310, accepted):

Use the <kbd>Hardware > Home</kbd>  menu item, or hit <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>

Comment: Thanks! I already used it. BTW: press Cmd-Shift-H two times to simulate action of "press home button twice".

Comment: why the heck did they take this away?!

Comment: I found this key combination may active slow motion (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624519/simulator-slow-motion-animations-are-now-on), quite annoying

Comment: So I just have to get both of my hands free from mouse and put them on keyboard to press CMD+Shift+h during testing? This is totally uncomfortable and annoying.. :-/

Comment: You hold your mouse with both hands? :)

Comment: It was a mistake in sentence btw. It should be like *get one hand free from mouse and assign both hands to press all 3 keys*.No but stretching palm/fingers to press all 3 keys at a time is quite uncomfortable and I need 2 hands for that.. At the time of testing thats quite annoying.:-)

Comment: You can also press and hold CMD key to see the list of shortcuts on screen.

Comment: It's Alt-Shift-H when remote desktop from Windows.

Comment: Someone told them that this was `innovation` and they all jumped and removed the button. The UX designer would have done tones of research to figure out what the most irritating thing would be for people wanting to use the simulator, and just innovated a way to fuel that irritation.

Answer (score 5):

Works great.  COMMAND+SHIFT+ H(double tap)

Comment: It's not formulated in a great way, but this actually provides some additional information (i.e how to get to the app switcher).

Comment: 2018 Post: This is still de facto.. Hit "H" twice or else you'll turn Siri on... ;)

Answer (score 4):

I want to say it's because they want us to remember the new resolution when debugging.

edit: My answer is to the title directly

Answer (score 1):

***iPhone Simulator Key Shortcuts***

```
Command-Left Arrow

Rotate left

Command-Right Arrow

Rotate right

Command-Shift-H
```

go home. leave the application and return to the springboard home screen

```
Command-L
```

simulates locking the phone