# Xcode iOS 7 simulator- no home button?

Tags: ios-simulator

I have download `Xcode` today ,and i can't see the home button in simulation.
I was trying to do `cmd+1` but it didn't work .
How i get back  the home button ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why there is no "Home" button in iPad simulator in iOS 5.1 SDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613262/why-there-is-no-home-button-in-ipad-simulator-in-ios-5-1-sdk)

Answer (score 155, accepted):

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd>

(wasn't obvious to me too when I first opened it)

Comment: Also, hit `⌘` + `Shift` + `H` twice/in quick succession for multitasking

Answer (score 15):

The Hardware tab will give you access to the home button, as well as other things such as rotate screen, shake screen, and lock the device. 
Good luck!