# How to click home button in iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, ios-ui-automation, keycode, appium-ios

1. I want to click home button in iOS Simulator by automation.
2. I just want to know whether it is possible to do click home button using IOS keycode event.

Comment: In `Simulator home button` is not available.

Comment: command +shift +h

Comment: also show in Hardware -> Home

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why there is no "Home" button in iPad simulator in iOS 5.1 SDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613262/why-there-is-no-home-button-in-ipad-simulator-in-ios-5-1-sdk)

Answer (score 24):

Are you want to find this flow accelerator key?
[image]

Answer (score 7):

Simply press Cmd + shift + H...

Answer (score 4):

Use combination shortcuts：<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

There are 3 ways depending what is convenient to you 
 1. If you are using MAC then you can use `Cmd + shift + H`
 2. If you are accessing Mac with VNC or such you can use `Shift + alt + H`
 3. In top options Select hardware-> home in MAC
[image: Image of 3rd method]

Answer (score 4):

### 2021 Latest Update: XCode 11.4

Click on the **home icon above simulator**.

[image]

Older option still available: **Ctrl + Shift + h**

Answer (score 1):

`Simulator` don't have `Home Button` but you can use following short cut `key`

`Ctrl + Shift + h` for navigate to `HomeScreen`

Answer (score 0):

To enable Home Button in device Button.
Select simulator -> Window -> Show device bezels

[Step - Step to show home button in sumulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBTLx.png)

[Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b24lQ.png)