# Slow in GUI Action

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

This is a general question in IOS. I have a view which is having some subviews (i have added those views using `insertSubview:atIndex:` method). If I remove those subviews by `removeFromSuperview` method, my main view will shown up, but all GUI actions are very slow in that view. for example: If I click text field on the main view , the keyboard appears very slowly and goes down slowly too. I don't know what have I done wrong. Any idea ?

Here is a sample code. self is my main view, I'm adding other two views in it.

```
(void) begin_action {
                subview1 =[[test_subview1 alloc] init];
                [self.view insertSubview:[self. subview1.view] atIndex:0];

        subview2 =[[test_subview2 alloc] init];
                [self.view insertSubview:[self.subview2.view] atIndex:1];
    }

    end_of_action {
           [self. subview1.view removeFromSuperview];
           [self. subview2.view removeFromSuperview];

           self. subview1 = nil;
           self. subview2 = nil;
    }
```

Other than this anything I need to do two remove a view?

thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please check whether there are any memory warnings.

Comment: I can't see anyone being able to answer your question with such little detail.  You'll need to post code I guess...

Comment: Have you accidentally activated slow animations in the simulator?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624519/simulator-slow-motion-animations-are-now-on

Comment: @dasdom No I don't think so. Once I created subviews those are behaving normal only.

Comment: Did you check this on an actual device? Also, try restarting the simulator

Comment: No I'm trying simulator only. Is it matters? That slowness happens exactly after removing the view only so I'm doubting any memory leak as Vaibhavi mentioned.

Comment: Yup! Your system might be getting slow for some reason

Comment: Ok then I will try with device..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check this on an actual device? Also, try restarting the simulator – tipycalFlow