# In Xcode how do I know if my lauch image is working correctly?

Tags: ios, xcode

When I run the simulator, the app opens really quickly so it's impossible to see the launch image.

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624519/simulator-slow-motion-animations-are-now-on

Comment: In `viewDidLoad`, put in `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0];`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Set a breakpoint to the 1st line of your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` delegate method. Or better yet, inside `main`.

This will pause the app before showing your user interface and allow you to see the launch screen.

Comment: will you actually get the launch screen. I would think the breakpoint would lock the UI... I need to try this :)

Comment: @logixologist Yes, this actually works. Remember, iOS shows the launch screen of your app before your app is actually executed and it stays in place until your app's root view controller is displayed. A simple breakpoint in `main` will show your launch screen just fine.

Answer (score 2):

1. Launch iOS simulator
2. Enable slow animations (`⌘` + `T`)
3. Launch your app.
4. Blink slowly

Answer (score 1):

Set below code 1st line of your application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
sleep(delay); // delay int value
```

Comment: Why 1 or 2 aren't possible?

Comment: any int value sleep(delay);

Comment: that should be in answer ;)

Comment: Problem with this approach is that you need to modify your code and if you turn away for a second, you miss it. A simple breakpoint as shown in my answer is much easier and doesn't require code changes that you might forget to remove.