# React-Native modal animation speed

Tags: react-native

I am currently using an example from here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html

While I can edit the animationType={"slide"} it seems to be transitioning very slow.

Is there a way to edit the transition speed of the slide?

Answer (score 8):

For anyone out there, its actually Xcode's issue

do cmnd + T and it will return to normal.

[Simulator slow-motion animations are now on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624519/simulator-slow-motion-animations-are-now-on)

Answer (score 0):

With library react-native-modal you can specify the duration of the In and out Animation

```
<Modal
        hasBackdrop={true}
        backdropOpacity={0.6}
        backdropColor="#000000"
        hideModalContentWhileAnimating={true}
        useNativeDriverForBackdrop={true}
        useNativeDriver={true}
        animationInTiming={1}
        animationOutTiming={1}
        backdropTransitionInTiming={1}
        backdropTransitionOutTiming={1}
        isVisible={isVisible}
        onBackdropPress={() => {
            closingFunc();
        }} />
```